# Como listar links de download pelo VBA

Tags: vba, lista, internet-explorer, link, click

Olá!

Meu problema é o seguinte... estou realizando o acesso a um site, onde forneço login e senha e viajo pelas páginas até minha página de interesse.

Tenho uma função que sempre lista todos os links da página ativa no IE.

O problema é que quando chego na minha página de interesse, que é onde está um link para baixar arquivo .rar, a função para listar links não me mostra exatamente este link de interesse.

Eu sou novo neste tipo de programação, então o que construí até agora são blocos que pesquisei em fóruns, talvez a solução seja simples, mas não está indo.

Segue abaixo o código... não posso fornecer informações da página final pois é particular, mas o que interessa é clicar no download.

```
Sub Lista_links(IE)

Set internetdata = IE.Document
Set internetlink = internetdata.getElementsByTagName("a")

I = 1

For Each internetinnerlink In internetlink

    ActiveSheet.Cells(I, 4) = internetinnerlink.href
    I = I + 1

Next internetinnerlink
End Sub

Sub FazerLoginSite()

Dim IE As Object

Set IE = CreateObject("InternetExplorer.application")

With IE
    .Visible = True

    .Navigate ("site primario")
    While .Busy Or .ReadyState <> 4: DoEvents: Wend

    On Error GoTo Ja_logado
    .Document.getElementById("auth_logout").Click
    While .Busy Or .ReadyState <> 4: DoEvents: Wend
    .Navigate ("site que me redireciona para o site de interesse")
    While .Busy Or .ReadyState <> 4: DoEvents: Wend

Ja_logado:
    .Navigate ("site de interesse")
    .Document.getElementById("id-username").Focus
    .Document.getElementById("id-username").Value = "meu login"
    .Document.getElementById("id-password").Focus
    .Document.getElementById("id-password").Value = "minha senha"
    .Document.forms(0).submit
    While .Busy Or .ReadyState <> 4: DoEvents: Wend

    .Navigate ("acessa um link específico na página")
    While .Busy Or .ReadyState <> 4: DoEvents: Wend
    '
    'Debug.Print .LocationURL

    Sheets("Plan1").Activate
    Call Lista_links(IE)

    .Navigate2 ("NESSA PARTE, EU ACESSO A PÁGINA QUE TEM O LINK PARA   DOWNLOAD"), CLng(2048)
    While .Busy Or .ReadyState <> 4: DoEvents: Wend


'NESSA PARTE DO CÓDIGO, QUANDO EU LISTO OS LINKS NOVAMENTE, O ÚNICO LINK QUE NÃO APARECE É O DE DOWNLOAD .RAR!
    Sheets("Plan2").Activate
    Call Lista_links(IE)

End With

'IE.Quit
Set IE = Nothing

End Sub
```

Comment: A variável I declarada como 1 deveria ser 0, não? Um vetor começa em 0 então acho que pode ser isso.